Anyone able to guide me
So I was using the website crypto Leo, and deposited $30 worth of ETH but for some reason it’s been sent to an address on etherscan 0x5495dAeE61D2c2143E92ECb2EA395042783cC4cd can anyone advise me what to do? As ethersacn isn’t a wallet service and I’ve tried linking it with wallet connect but it’s t working at all. Thanks in advance.
